# POST binary data without intermediary temp file

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to upload a file using Python requests, but I already have the file as binary data.
The only way I can get it to work is by writing the binary data to file and opening that file again:

```
with open("tempfile.tmp", 'wb+') as tmp:
    tmp.write(binary_data)
    tmp.seek(0)
    files = {'file_input': tmp}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

It seems to me this should be possible without the temp file.
I unsuccessfully tried this:

```
data = {'file_input': binary_data}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: I needed to provide a filename.

```
r = requests.post(url, files={'file_input': ("tempfile.tmp", binary_data)})
```

Thanks snakecharmerb for pointing me in the right direction.